# OperationalError: no such column -- occurring when the column does exist

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlite

I'm trying out Django for the first time and I'm having some trouble querying from my models.

This is my model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=128, primary_key=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    count = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

When I run `$> python manage.py sql users`, I get:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "users_user" (
    "user" varchar(128) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "password" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    "count" integer NOT NULL
)
;
```

When I fire up the interactive shell via `$> python manage.py shell`, I get an error when I try to retrieve my User objects. I know there's none, but it should return an empty list.

```
$> python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from users.models import User
>>> User.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 71, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 96, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 854, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 220, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 709, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 782, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 450, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
OperationalError: no such column: users_user.user
>>>
```

Upon calling `>>> User.objects.all()` (after importing via `>>> from users.models import User`), I get an error saying:

'OperationalError: no such column: users_user.user'

How can this be if that column shows up when I run '`$> python manage.py sql users`'?

Comment: Have you performed `python manage.py syncdb` ?

Comment: @PriyankPatel yes i have, multiple times. even `python manage.py flush`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`manage.py sql` shows you what SQL *would* be run if you're creating the tables from scratch. And `syncdb` does not modify existing tables.

You need to drop your table and run syncdb again. In the future, use South.

Comment: thanks! but doesn't `python manage.py flush` basically drop everything?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#flush - as you can see it only drops data from your database.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and fixed with :

```
class Email(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

Running:

```
python manage.py sql emails
```

I got :

```
BEGIN; CREATE TABLE "emails_email" (
       "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
       "name" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
       "email" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
       "pub_date" datetime NOT NULL ) ;

COMMIT;
```

So Django already create an primary key , we don't need create one or it seems we shouldn't create one .